# Why User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false only in IMiddleware

Tags: asp.net, authentication, swagger, asp.net-core-middleware

I have following code :

```
//register in DI
services.AddSingleton<SwaggerAuthMiddleware>();
```

```
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.ConfigureExceptionHandler(logger);

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseResponseCompression();
            app.UseSaml2();

            app.UseAuthorization();
           
            app.UseMiddleware<SwaggerAuthMiddleware>();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyApplication");
            });
```

In swaggerAuthMiddleware I just have :

```
 public class SwaggerAuthMiddleware : IMiddleware
    {
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            var isAuthenticated = context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            await next.Invoke(context);
            var isAuthenticated2 = context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            var stopper = 1;
        }
    }
```

both isAuthenticated and isAuthenticated2 are false if I will send request to swagger/index.html.

If I will send request to any controller (for example /getPersons which also needs to be authenticated) , then it's true.

Interesting is also fact, that If I paste request to controller (/getPersons) into postman and hit this middleware with cookies, both are true. Then if I will change just path to swagger/index.html and leave all cookies as they are, isAuthenticated both are false.

Why it is false? Why it not gives me authentication despite that cookies are included into request?

Comment: sorry, I can't reproduce your issue, I had a windows authentication api project and I added the middleware with your code, but when I add a break point in the middle then visit the `swagger/index.html` page, the app didn't stop their. so I also can't check if it's authenticated or not.

Comment: which authentication sechma you are using?